# Copy specific word section to new document in python

Tags: python, ms-word, docx, aspose, aspose.words

As the title says, I'm trying to copy a select section of text to a new word document. Basically, I have a bunch of annual reports with sections that are systemically named (i.e. Project 1, Project 2, etc..) I want to be able to search for a select section and copy that section into a report for the individual project. I've been looking through docx documentation and aspose.words documentation. This is the closest I've gotten to what I'm looking for but it's still not quite right:

```
# For complete examples and data files, please go to https://github.com/aspose-words/Aspose.Words-for-Python-via-.NET
doc = aw.Document(docs_base.my_dir + "Big document.docx")

for i in range(0, doc.sections.count) :
        
# Split a document into smaller parts, in this instance, split by section.
section = doc.sections[i].clone()

newDoc = aw.Document()
newDoc.sections.clear()

newSection = newDoc.import_node(section, True).as_section()
newDoc.sections.add(newSection)

# Save each section as a separate document.
newDoc.save(docs_base.artifacts_dir + f"SplitDocument.by_sections_{i}.docx")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect by saying section you mean just content tat starts with some heading paragraph. This does not correspond to `Section` node in [Aspose.Words Document Object Model](https://docs.aspose.com/words/python-net/aspose-words-document-object-model/). Section in MS Word are used if you need to have different page setup or headers/footers within the document.

It is difficult to say without your document, but I suppose there is only one section in your document. It looks like you need to [extract content form the document based on the styles](https://docs.aspose.com/words/python-net/how-to-extract-selected-content-between-nodes-in-a-document/#extract-content-between-paragraphs-based-on-style).
Also, I have create a simple code example that demonstrates the basic technique:

```py
import aspose.words as aw

# Geneare document with heading paragraphs (just for demonstrations purposes).
doc = aw.Document()
builder = aw.DocumentBuilder(doc)

for i in range(0, 5):
    builder.paragraph_format.style_identifier = aw.StyleIdentifier.HEADING1
    builder.writeln("Project {0}".format(i))
    builder.paragraph_format.style_identifier = aw.StyleIdentifier.NORMAL
    for j in range(0, 10):
        builder.writeln("This is the project {0} content {1}, each project section will be extracted into a separate document.".format(i, j))

doc.save("C:\\Temp\\out.docx")

# Now split the document by heading paragraphs.
# Code is just for demonstration purposes and supposes there is only one section in the document.
subDocumentIndex = 0
subDocument = doc.clone(False).as_document()
for child in doc.first_section.body.child_nodes:
    if child.node_type == aw.NodeType.PARAGRAPH and child.as_paragraph().paragraph_format.style_identifier == aw.StyleIdentifier.HEADING1:
        if not subDocument.has_child_nodes:
            subDocument.ensure_minimum()
        else:
            # save subdocument
            subDocument.save("C:\\Temp\\sub_document_{0}.docx".format(subDocumentIndex))
            subDocumentIndex = subDocumentIndex+1
            subDocument = doc.clone(False).as_document()
            subDocument.ensure_minimum()
        # Remove body content.
        subDocument.first_section.body.remove_all_children()

    # import current node to the subdocument.
    dst_child = subDocument.import_node(child, True, aw.ImportFormatMode.USE_DESTINATION_STYLES)
    subDocument.first_section.body.append_child(dst_child)

# save the last document.
subDocument.save("C:\\Temp\\sub_document_{0}.docx".format(subDocumentIndex))
```